# There exists a divisor linearly equivalent to $P$ not containing $P$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a non-singular projective curve over $\mathbb C$ and let $P\in  X$ be a closed point. Which is, in your opinion,  the easiest way to prove that there exists a divisor $D$ of $X$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. $D$ is linearly equivalent to $P$.
2. $D$ doesn't contain $P$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want $D$ to be effective?

Comment: No, it should be only linear eqivalent to $P$

Comment: Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be nonsingular hyperplane sections of $X$ such that $P$ lies in $H_1$ but not $H_2$. The divisor you want is $D=P-H_1+H_2$.

Comment: Ok, but why? I can't understand completely the reason.

Comment: Dear @Relapsarian, you should turn your great comment into an answer : I'm burning to upvote you and so should every knowledgeable user who happens to read your elegant, geometric solution !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it on good authority that Relapsarian is suffering an identity crisis at the moment, so let me post the comment above as an answer as per @GeorgesElencwajg's impassioned suggestion.

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be nonsingular hyperplane sections of $X$ such that $P$ lies in $H_1$ but not $H_2$. Then the divisor you want is $D=P−H_1+H_2$. Why? "Nonsingular" means that each hyperplanes is intersecting $X$ transversely; that implies in particular that the divisor $H_1$ contains $P$ with coefficient 1. On the other hand $P$ is not in $H_2$, so in the divisor $P-H_1+H_2$ we end up with no term involving $P$.

Finally, (exercise!) any two hyperplanes in projective space are linearly equivalent, and linear equivalence is preserved by restriction, so $-H_1+H_2$ is a principal divisor on $X$.

Comment: Do you mean that Relapsarian suffers from dissociative identity disorder and that one of his/her personalities is that of  a beautiful Egyptian princess ?

Comment: No, something a bit more prosaic: Relapsarian suffers from can't-remember-login-details disorder, but wanted to answer a question about *nef* line bundles.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand: why does answering a question on *nef* bundles prevent Relapsarian from posting an answer to  *manifold*'s question?  Anyway, thanks a lot for taking the trouble to post an answer, Nefertiti.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, let me try to explain: I couldn't log in from a certain location, so I answered the question on **nef** line bundles using a different account. I had to think of a name for the new account, and, given the subject matter **Nef**ertiti was the first thing that popped into my mind.

Comment: Ah, I see: thanks for the explanation and for making me laugh with your creative handle. And, much more seriously, bravo again for your perfect answer. I hope to read much from you here in the future.